# How to initialize a search call?

Tags: angular, observable, subject

I have a component which basically consists of a text-box (input) and a display area of the results:

[image]

```html
<div class="row search">
  <div class="col">
    <input
      id="iptSearch"
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="search blueprints"
      (keyup)="keyUp$.next($event.target.value)"
    />
  </div>
</div>

<ng-container *ngIf="courses$ | async as courses; else loadingCourses">

  <table class="table table-borderless table-responsive-sm">
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of courses | slice: (page-1) * pageSize : (page-1) * pageSize + pageSize">
        <ew-browse-courses [course]=item></ew-browse-courses>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <ngb-pagination
    [(page)]="page"
    [pageSize]="pageSize"
    [collectionSize]="courses.length">
  </ngb-pagination>

</ng-container>

<ng-template #loadingCourses>
  <div class="spinner-border"></div>
</ng-template>
```

In the component I use a Subject and a Service (both observables) to fetch the search text and send it to the Service:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { CourseBrowse } from '../_models/course';
import { CourseService } from '../_services/course.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'ew-course-home',
  templateUrl: './course-home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course-home.component.css']
})
export class CourseHomeComponent implements OnInit {
  courses$: Observable<CourseBrowse[]>;
  keyUp$ = new Subject<string>();

  // pagination
  pageSize = 5;
  page = 1;

  constructor(private courseService: CourseService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  
   // that was another attempt (mimic an "onkeyup")
   // const element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('iptSearch') as HTMLElement;
   // element.onkeyup; // that's a property of course - there's no method like "keypress"

    this.courses$ = this.keyUp$.pipe(
      // filter(term => term.length >= 3),
      debounceTime(500),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(searchTerm => this.courseService.searchCourses(searchTerm))
    );

    this.keyUp$.next(''); // my ideas was to just send and empty string
  }
}
```

The search itself works fine, my problem is that i can't initiate it. If the component is shown, it would just wait for an input...

[image]

if the user focuses the input-box and hits enter (search for an empty string) the service returns the whole list (limited to 50) as intended.

So what I want to do now, is to send that empty string to the Subject to execute this search first. My approaches using keyUp$.next('') didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you make a test with one character?  With keUp$ being a Subject<string> i wonder if an empty string pass the distinctUntilChanged rxjs operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the startWith operator

```
this.courses$ = this.keyUp$.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      // filter(term => term.length >= 3),
      debounceTime(500),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(searchTerm => this.courseService.searchCourses(searchTerm))
    );
```